# Как обратиться к n-ому объекту из сортированного массива полей объекта?

Tags: java

Как обратиться к n-ому объекту из сортированного массива полей объекта?

```
public class GuessTheNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player play1 = new Player();
        play1.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play1.name+" понадобилось "+play1.attempts+" попыток.");

        Player play2 = new Player();
        play2.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play2.name+" понадобилось "+play2.attempts+" попыток.");

        Player play3 = new Player();
        play3.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play3.name+" понадобилось "+play3.attempts+" попыток.");

        int [] mas = new int [] {play1.attempts,play2.attempts,play3.attempts};

      Arrays.sort(mas);
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(mas[i]+" "+//здесь необходимо вывести play[i].name);

        }
    }
}

class Player{

    int attempts;
    String name;}
```

Comment: Создайте массив Player[] players, и обращайтесь к полям объектов массива.

Comment: А как отсортировать тогда результаты?

Comment: Можно вместо массива использовать списки из коллекции Java, где уже предусмотрена сортировка, либо самому написать сортировку по нужному полю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простым вариантом решение вашей задачи является имплементация интерфейса Comparable.
Вносим изменения в класс Player:

```
class Player implements Comparable<Player>{
   ....
   /*
     метод сравнивает два объекта(если объекты равны, возвращаем ноль,
     иначе < или > 0 соотвественно)
   */
   public int compareTo(Player p){
      return attempts.compareTo(p.attempts());
   }
}
```

Далее создаем структуру данных, которая изначально поддерживает отсортированную последовательность: Например TreeSet:

```
new TreeSet<Player>
```

заполняем коллекцию. В процессе заполнения коллекция будет поддерживать порядок на основе вашего компаратора. 
Либо вы можете создать массив как раньше и так же использовать метод

```
Arrays.sort
```